# Testing infinite series for convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ne^{-n^2}$

How would one go about showing convergence? Which test can be used?

Comment: Note $\frac{n}{e^{n^2}}\le \frac{n}{1+n^2+\frac12n^4}$.

Comment: How did you find the series to comapare it with?

Comment: Continuing we have $\frac{n}{1+n^2+\frac14 n^4}\le \frac{2}{n^3}$

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)? The series
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty ne^{-n^2}$$ converges if and only if the improper integral $$\int_N^\infty xe^{-x^2}\,dx$$ is finite.

Comment: Oh yeah that works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you mainly have two tests (ratio and root test). Try them both, you'll see which one works best.

Answer (score 0):

You may observe that
$$
\lim_{n \to +\infty}\left(n^3 e^{-n^2} \right)=0
$$ giving, an integer $n_0$ such that for all $n \geq n_0$, we have
$$
n e^{-n^2}\leq \frac1{n^2}
$$ and by comparison
$$
\sum_{n \geq n_0}n e^{-n^2}\leq \sum_{n \geq n_0}\frac1{n^2}<\infty
$$ your initial series is then **convergent**.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum ne^{-n^2} = - \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dn}\sum e^{-n^2}$$

Which you know it to be an absolute convergent series, then it's derivative it's convergent.